# React Native: Calling API running on localhost

Tags: .net, rest, react-native, .net-core, expo

I have an API that I'm running locally on my machine. I'm trying to access this data in a development environment and running into issues.

When I have my React Native app running through expo, `localhost` is referring to the devices localhost and not the one running on my desktop. I have researched this quite a bit and the top suggestion is to query your internal IP address instead of `localhost`.

When I query `localhost` I get an exception thrown with no details:

`Network request failed`

When I query my internal IP, the request hangs and nothing happens.

I'm starting expo through this command: `expo start --tunnel`

Here is the code making the request:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5001/api/standings")
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

The `.NET` API works through chrome. On both `localhost` and my internal IP (with a warning about an unsecure connection).

I there any additional configuration I'm missing?

EDIT:

Here is the Postman response:

[image: Postman]

Here is my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddHttpClient();
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddEnv((builder) =>
        {
            builder
            .AddEnvFile(".env")
            .AddThrowOnError(true)
            .AddEncoding(Encoding.ASCII);
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseCors(builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to expose your API?

In the team I work on what we do when we want to test our version of the API running in the localhost, while also running the mobile app in our simulators, is to expose the local version of the API with ngrok and point our app to ngrok's URL.

> ngrok exposes local servers behind NATs and firewalls to the public internet over secure tunnels.

Here's a [guide](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/tutorials/how-use-ngrok-windows-and-visual-studio-test-webhooks) that should help with getting ngrok up and running in a Windows machine.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll award the bounty when the timer is finished.

Comment: Glad it helped @23k . If you could also accept my answer as the correct one that would be great.

Comment: Don't you need internet for ngrok, which introduce requirements and latency?

Comment: Yes, if that's a problem for your test scenario then NGROK is not the best tool for you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a cross-origin issue. You can't send a request to another domain. Need **to enable Cross-Origin Request**.

How to do it for **asp.net core** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

How to do it for **asp.net webapi** - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Both links have great explanations.

Comment: Doesn't look like that was the solution. I've added some additional code and a screenshot from Postman.